# Conditional Pod linking for MacCatalyst

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, mac-catalyst

Flurry Analytics is still not supported by MacCatalyst. In my App, Flurry is the only CocoaPod not supported in that targetEnvironment. Fernando Moya de Rivas had a nice article in Medium on conditional linking for this very problem (https://medium.com/better-programming/macos-catalyst-debugging-problems-using-catalyst-and-cocoapods-579679150fa9).
The pod is a static, precompiled library.
Moya de Rivas suggested editing the xcconfig file to conditionally link files if they were iOS only from:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework "Crashlytics" -framework "Fabric" -framework "FrameworkThatSupportsCatalyst"
```

to:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework "FrameworkThatSupportsCatalyst"
OTHER_LDFLAGS[iphone*] = $(inherited) -framework "Crashlytics" -framework "Fabric"
```

so, in my xcconfig, I removed Flurry_iOS_SDK from the load list and put it in the iOS only list:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -framework "Accelerate" -framework "CFNetwork" -framework "CalmParametricAnimations" -framework "CampcotCollectionView" -framework "CoreGraphics"   -framework "Foundation" -framework "KenBurns" -framework "Kingfisher" -framework "QuartzCore" -framework "Security" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -framework "UIKit"
OTHER_LDFLAGS[iphone*] = $(inherited) -framework "Flurry_iOS_SDK"
```

The problem is that Xcode does not seem to like the conditional link statement:

```
xxxxxxx.debug.xcconfig Ignoring build settings configuration file Pods-HieroglyphicsPro.debug.xcconfig due to an error: String 'OTHER_LDFLAGS[iphone*] = $(inherited) -framework "Flurry_iOS_SDK"' could not be parsed: macro string representation 'OTHER_LDFLAGS[iphone*]' isn't well formed: parameter name is empty.
```

Moya de Rivas' approach is widely quoted as a good solution, but I am using a later version of Xcode (12.2 release 12B45b).  Is this syntax no longer supported, or do I have a syntax error I do not see? I was unable to find a reference to commands for the Xcode linker toolchain.

Answer (score 2):

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS[iphone*] = $(inherited) -framework "Flurry_iOS_SDK"
```

works better as

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphone*] = $(inherited) -framework "Flurry_iOS_SDK"
```